# Using span tag in JavaScript to modify contents inside html <p> tags

Tags: javascript, html

Say we have the following code:

```
<html>
<body>
<p id="income"></p>
</body>
<script>
var income = 95350.23
document.getElementById("income").innerHTML = 'Income <span style = "float:right;">' + income + '</span>'
</script>
</html>
```

How do we fix this code? I'm trying to make the contents inside the

tag state: "Income" on the left and 95,350.23 on the far right.

Thank you!

Comment: I am just assuming a blank web page. "Income" on the very left and the variable income on the very right. Do you know how to do this? I was suggested using the span tag in a previous post. I can try to figure out the rest in the context of my actual code (i.e. I will figure out the true positioning) but I do need some guidance on how to do the basics first.

Comment: Notice on the position of the `script` tag: you should put it at the end BEFORE the closing `</body>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

You have syntax errors in your code, you forgot to concatenate `income` with the rest of the string with `+`.

```js
var income = 95350.23;
document.getElementById("income").innerHTML = 'Income <span style = "float:right;">' + income + '</span>';
```

```html
<p id="income"></p>
```

Comment: @GaryC you can also use to [toLocaleString()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tolocalestring.asp) to use locale conventions.

Answer (score 0):

```
var income = 95;   
document.getElementById("income").innerHTML = "Income " + "<span style = 
"+"float:right;"+">"+income+"</span>"

change the initialization of income
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I'm extending the answer from @julekgwa with the method `toLocaleString`, which prints out a number in local format. Please pay attention to the output (comma and point).
As I understand, this is a requirement in your question.

```js
var income = 95350.23;
document.getElementById("income").innerHTML = 'Income' +
    '<span style = "float:right;">' +
        income.toLocaleString('en-US') + 
    '</span>';
```

```html
<p id="income"></p>
```